# How to show video in Carousel in Ember JS

Tags: ember.js, carousel

I am newbie in ember. In this ember app, the legacy code displays Images, but I want to add some videos between the images.

My test code is given as below, here simply replace the image with video.

```
    {{!-- Carousel --}}
{{#bs-carousel
    class=(concat "carousel" (if imagesLoading ' invisible height-none'))
    autoPlay=false
    interval=0
    wrap=true
    model=imageCaptures
    showControls=showControls
    showIndicators=showIndicators
    index=activeImage
    as |caro|}}
    {{#each imageCaptures as |slide|}}
        {{#caro.slide}}

            {{!-- <img alt='' src='{{slide.image_url}}'> --}}
            <video>
              <source src='{{slide.image_url}} type="video/mp4"'>
            </video>

        {{/caro.slide}}
    {{/each}}
{{/bs-carousel}}
```

Video is shown, but it is cut, not auto scaled in the div where the image was shown.
Can you tell me how to display video in Carousel?

Answer (score 1):

## ember-carousel

An ember addon for Carousel component

[DEMO](http://selvagsz.github.io/ember-carousel)

### Usage

From within your Ember CLI application, run the following:

```
ember install ember-carousel
```

Add invoke the component as follows

```
{{#carousel-container transitionInterval=400 as |ui controls|}}
  <div class="carousel-body">
    {{#ui.item}}
      Emberjs
    {{/ui.item}}
    {{#ui.item}}
      Reactjs
    {{/ui.item}}
    {{#ui.item}}
      Angularjs
    {{/ui.item}}
  </div>

  <button onclick={{controls.previous}}>
    Slide Left
  </button>
  <button onclick={{controls.next}}>
    Slide Right
  </button>
{{/carousel-container}}
```

### API

#### `{{carousel-container}}`

This is the primary component to start displaying carousel items.

Attributes

- `transitionInterval` - Defaults to `500`.
- `onSlide` - Optional, an action that receives one parameter, an object like `{ index: 3, previousIndex: 2, direction: 'right' }`.
  Triggered before the transition is completed.

Yielded Params

This component yields two hashes, e.g. `{{#carousel-container as |ui act|}}`.
These parameters `ui` and `act` can be called anything, but they contain the following items:

- `ui` - is a hash with the following component items:

  - `item` - A component that should contain your slide contents, used like so `{{ui.item}}you content{{/ui.item}}`.
- `controls` - is a hash with the following action items:

  - `previous` - A closure action that changes to the previous slide.
  - `next` - A closure action that changes to the next slide.

### Development

- `git clone` this repository
- `npm install`
- `bower install`

### Running

- `ember server`
- Visit your app at http://localhost:4200.

### Running Tests

- `ember test`
- `ember test --server`

### Building

- `ember build`

For more information on using ember-cli, visit http://www.ember-cli.com/.

SOURCE:https://github.com/selvagsz/ember-carousel#readme